# gprof inside docker container -> no time accumulated

Tags: docker, gprof

I have a project (octave-4.2.1 tarball) compiled with gcc 6.3 on debian stretch with grpof. If I run it directly on the host, gmon.out is generated and the output of gprof shows timing infos.

If I build the same code with excactly the same flags inside a docker container based on stretch-lite and run it I get:

```
warning: ignoring unexpected signal: Profiling timer expired
```

and the prof generated output shows:

```
no time accumulated
```

and all timing infos are zero.

I guess (really just a wild guess) gprof needs some sort of direct kernel access to get timing infos. Any ideas if this is possible and how a docker container might "directly" talk to the kernel?